# Is it possible to apply NOT(!) operator while DataBinding a property of a control?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have Button control and I have to set the IsEanbled property based on the bool variable.

```
bool IsBoolVariable
```

I want if **IsBoolVariable** property is **true** then I want to set the **IsEnabled** property to **false** AND when **IsBoolVariable** property is **false** then I want to set the **IsEnabled** property to **true**.

Is it possible to apply not(!) operator while defining the binding as given below

```
<Button
IsEnabled = "{Binding Path = **!**IsBoolVariable}" />
```

I can very well do that by applying convertors , but that is the only way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes, converters are the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind it to a bool Property that returns false when IsEnabled is true....